# GWT compile warning

Tags: gwt

I get the below warning when I try to compile my GWT project:

```
Specify -logLevel DEBUG to see all errors.
             [java]             
     [WARN] Unknown type 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver' specified in deferred binding rule
             [java]    Scanning for additional dependencies: jar:file:<GWT_PATH>/2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCellBase.java
             [java]       Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.google.gwt.cell.client.ButtonCellBase.DefaultAppearance.Template'
             [java]          Rebinding com.google.gwt.cell.client.ButtonCellBase.DefaultAppearance.Template
             [java]             Invoking generator com.google.gwt.safehtml.rebind.SafeHtmlTemplatesGenerator
             [java]                Constructing interface com.google.gwt.cell.client.ButtonCellBase.DefaultAppearance.Template
             [java]                   Generating method body for iconContentLayout()
             [java]                      
    [WARN] Template with variable in CSS attribute context: The template code generator cannot guarantee HTML-safety of the template -- please inspect manually or use Safe
        Styles to specify arguments in a CSS attribute context
             [java]                      
    [WARN] Template with variable in CSS attribute context: The template code generator cannot guarantee HTML-safety of the template -- please inspect manually or use Safe
        Styles to specify arguments in a CSS attribute context
             [java]                   Generating method body for iconWrapper()
             [java]                      
    [WARN] Template with variable in CSS attribute context: The template code generator cannot guarantee HTML-safety of the template -- please inspect manually or use Safe
        Styles to specify arguments in a CSS attribute context
             [java]                      
    [WARN] Template with variable in CSS attribute context: The template code generator cannot guarantee HTML-safety of the template -- please inspect manually or use Safe
            Styles to specify arguments in a CSS attribute context
              [java]    Compiling 6 permutations
              [java]       Compiling permutation 0...
              [java]       Compiling permutation 1...
              [java]       Compiling permutation 2...
              [java]       Compiling permutation 3...
              [java]       Compiling permutation 4...
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this warning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT "Template with variable in CSS attribute context" Warning is bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147978/gwt-template-with-variable-in-css-attribute-context-warning-is-bad)

Answer (score 0):

The warning tells you to use `style='{theStyle}'` where theStyle is an instance of SafeStyles, and not to use something like `style='width:{theWidth}'` for CSS formatting.

Comment: I have lots of files in my project. How can I know where this warning is coming from. Can you give me some example.

I have been setting style like below:
Button newBttn = new Button();
newBttn.setStyleName("style1");